# Alamofire impossible to create throw inside .responseJSON

Tags: swift2, alamofire

I have this method to contact my REST webservice.
I want to generate an exception when or connection fails.
Xcode tells me that I can not use a function throw `VendingMachineError.InvalidSelection` because the `method .responseJSON {(request, response, JSON) in` ecc ... can not do the conversion.
How can I fix this? thanks for your help.
[image]

Comment: if you have solved then put your answer as an answer so that it may be helpful for others.

Answer (score 3):

**SOLVED**
I solved this by putting error

```
do {
    throw NSError(domain: "howdy", code: 1, userInfo:nil)
} catch let error as NSError {
    print( "entrato nel catch primo \(error)")
}
```

In this way my error can be inherited by other methods. Complete code:

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://localhost:8080/progetto/login", headers: headers)
          ///  .validate(statusCode: 200..<200)
            .validate(contentType: ["application/json"])

            .responseJSON {(request,response, JSON) in

                switch JSON{
                case .Success(let data):
                    let result = data as! NSDictionary
                    let codeResponse = response?.statusCode
                    completionHandler(elements: result,stausCode: codeResponse!)
                    print("ciao sono entrato")

                case .Failure( _, let error):
                    print("sono entrato nel fallimento \(error)")
                    do {
                        throw NSError(domain: "howdy", code: 1, userInfo:nil)
                    } catch let error as NSError {
                        print( "entrato nel catch primo \(error)")
                    }
                }

            }

    }
```

Comment: In that case the error still not going to father's method (`login() throws`)